# Azure - Docker image disk full

Tags: azure, docker

I have a dockerized application deployed to Azure as an Application Service. After a several deployments I have got the following error:
[image]

The linux service which pulls the docker image for running it seems to be full. But I'm not sure where are these images pulled, because the File system storage tab says that only 4% of the storage is used.

I have tried both using the image from the ACR registry and from our private repository, the issue was the same.

I have tried also to connect via ssh but doesn't seem neither there to be full something.

Changing the Service plan from S1 to S2 solved the problem, but I would prefer to have a solution where I can do a clean up of the old images/resources or something similar.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

EDIT:

Checking the logs, basically the docker container start failed:

```
InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:449: container init caused \\\"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\\\\\"/var/LWASFiles/Sites/<site>/appsvctmp\\\\\\\" to rootfs \\\\\\\"/mnt/data/docker/images/231072.231072/aufs/mnt/a09dddec5e34cf18d12715faf148185e0fd74ae31e634f5f58f7a5525c89571a\\\\\\\" at \\\\\\\"/mnt/data/docker/images/231072.231072/aufs/mnt/a09dddec5e34cf18d12715faf148185e0fd74ae31e634f5f58f7a5525c89571a/appsvctmp\\\\\\\" caused \\\\\\\"mkdir /mnt/data/docker/images/231072.231072/aufs/mnt/a09dddec5e34cf18d12715faf148185e0fd74ae31e634f5f58f7a5525c89571a/appsvctmp: no space left on device\\\\\\\"\\\"\": unknown"}
```

Comment: The issue is about the image size, Maybe you need to remove useless things in the image. Or use a smaller base image or use multiple steps to reduce the garbage in the progress.